# sfdx community commands not working

Tags: apex, javascript, community, salesforcedx

I am trying to run few sfdx force:community commands to create and publish communities but getting few errors.

When trying to run

```
 sfdx force:community:create -n "TestPortal" -t "Build Your Own (LWR)" -p portal templateParams.AuthenticationType=UNAUTHENTICATED
```

I am getting an error "**HTTP method not allowed.**"

and when running the below command after creating community manually in the UI

```
sfdx force:community:publish -n "TestPortal"
```

I get "**requested resource does not exist**"

I have updated cli and communities enabled in the scratch org, also none of the other devs in the team has this issue which makes me believe the general setup is right. This is happening specially with community commands as all other sfdx commands are working fine, does anyone know any possible solution for this

Comment: Not saying it is the reason or solution, but are you on the latest sfdx CLI version?

Comment: did you enable community in your scratch org? or post your project-scratrch-def.json

Comment: @PhilW Yes I tried this even after updating the cli,

Comment: @sdandamud1 Yes I have added communities this in the scratch org definition file, strangely none of the other devs in the team has this issue so I believe the setup is right.

Comment: If it only happens to you, it is likely something environmental - something on your environment. If not sfdx CLI version, perhaps the version of Node.js you are using? Compare with what someone else is using to see if there is a difference here.

Comment: Are you running this command right after the scratch org is created or have you tried after some time (and the same error)?

Comment: @PhilW just updated my nodeJS from version 14 to the current stable one v16.14 but still the problem persists

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I ran this command after some time as there were changes from source control that needed to be deployed

Answer (score 2):

I did a fresh reinstall of the sfdx cli which fixed the issue for me